# URLencoding doesn't work

Tags: php, html, parsing, variables, encode

The $words variables are spanish words which my page looks for their meanings fetching them from www.rae.es .
Some spanish words have acute accents (á é ú í ó). If the user enters "baúl", it does not recognize it. I know i should use function url_encode($words) to encode it into " ba%FAl " (which works) but it doesnt work. Here is the majority of the PHP code:

```
    <?php

    // create an array of requests that we want
    // to load in the url.
    $words = array('word','word0','word1','word2','word3','word4','word5');

    function url_encode($string){
    return urlencode(utf8_encode($string));
    }

    // we'll use this later on for loading the files.
    $baseUrl = 'http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=';

    // string to replace in the head.
    $cssReplace = <<<EOT

    <style type="text/css">
    //bla bla bla
    </style>
    </head>
    EOT;

    // string to remove in the document.
    $spanRemove = '<span class="f"><b>.</b></span>';
    $styleRemove = 

    // use for printing out the result ID.
    $resultIndex = 0;

    // loop through the words we defined above
    // load the respective file, and print it out.
    foreach($words as $word) {
    // check if the request with
    // the given word exists. If not,
    // continue to the next word
    if(!isset($_REQUEST[$word]))
    continue;

    // load the contents of the base url and requested word.
    $contents = file_get_contents($baseUrl . $_REQUEST[$word]);

    // replace the data defined above.
    $contents = str_replace('</head>', $cssReplace, $contents);
    $contents = str_replace($spanRemove,"", $contents);

    // print out the result with the result index.
    // ++$resultIndex simply returns the value of 
    // $resultIndex after adding one to it.
    echo '<div id="result" style="
      margin-top:-80px;
      overflow:scroll; 
      width:800px; 
      height:150px;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      border-radius: 15px;
      background-opacity: 0.5;
      background: #047C8F;
      -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
      -moz-border-radius: 15px;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 13px #000000;
      -moz-box-shadow:
                   0px 3px 13px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
                   inset 0px 0px 13px rgba(0,0,0,1);
      -webkit-box-shadow:
                   0px 3px 13px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
                   inset 0px 0px 13px rgba(0,0,0,1);
     ', (++$resultIndex) ,'">', $contents ,
        '</div>',
        '<br/>',
        '<br/>',
        '<br/>',
        '<br/>',
        '<br/>';
        }
        ?>
```

**Focus on the code above the style replacement**

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Are you actually calling url_encode? Doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call url_encode...

Change this

```
$contents = file_get_contents($baseUrl . $_REQUEST[$word]);
```

into this

```
$contents = file_get_contents($baseUrl . url_encode($_REQUEST[$word]));
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function url_encode() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/IBProject/verbumpost.php on line 588

Comment: the code above works with your example.. you have to ensure, that the url_encode function is included, if the declaration is in another file